# Python top 100 ngrams

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

Does anyone know the best way to get the top 100 ngram, bigram, and trigram from a corpus?  For example, I have product reviews from 1500 products. I am looking to extract the top 100 terms. The terms are sometimes 1 word, 2 words, 3 words, etc.

I tried TFIDF vectorizer and NLTK ngrams however, the problem I'm having is that they both give all the combinations of all words instead of the most frequent terms or are limited to only 1gram, bigram or trigram.

Comment: Do you need n separate top 100 lists of ngrams (top 100 1grams, top 100 bigrams, top 100 trigrams,...) or top 100 of all of them amalgamated ? If it this the latter, you're going to get almost only 1grams in the top 100 because all other ngrams will have fewer (or the same number of) instances as their individual composing words.

Comment: @AlainT.Top 100 of all of them amalgamated.